# Header files and functions, is my function, parameters, or header prototype?

Tags: c, function, header-files, function-prototypes

I just started with C and am tasked with using a header to house a prototype for a function. The problem is that nothing happens when I'm expecting a prompt for input. I didn't get an error and would like to know where to look at first to solve my problem. This is what I have so far.

LAB2.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "LAB2HEADER.h"
int main(){
double *p;
double array [10];
p = array;
const int size = 10;
void input(p,size);
return 0;
}
```

LAB2HEADER.h

```
#ifndef LAB2HEADER_H_
#define LAB2HEADER_H_

void input (double *array,const int size);




#endif
```

LAB2HEADER.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "LAB2HEADER.h"

void input (double *array,const int size){
for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++)
{
    printf("Input a value");
    scanf("%lf", &array[i]);
}
}
```

A lot of the notes I look at seem to only either use Int as a parameter or have a function with no needed parameters, could my mistake be in my array pointer is it a problem with the way I made my function?

Comment: That's funny. When I try your code, I get `error: variable or field 'input' declared void`. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18167936b375d806

Comment: Please do not put the content of the `c` file into the `h` file. The definitions do not belong in headers, and the definition of `printf` is not in `stdio.h`.

Comment: `void input(p,size);` should be just `input(p,size)` you dont define a function while calling it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void input(p,size);
```

This line makes no sense. If this is supposed to be a function call, you need to remove `void`.

Answer (score 1):

Also, since your print statement does not end with a newline, nor do you flush stdout before reading in the value, your prompt might still be in the output buffer and not be output until you hit the newline AFTER entering the value.